# Get a number from an array of digits

Tags: julia, radix, digits

To split a number into digits in a given base, Julia has the [`digits()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/index.html#Base.digits) function:

```
julia> digits(36, base = 4)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 1
 2
```

What's the reverse operation? If you have an array of digits and the base, is there a **built-in** way to convert that to a number? I could print the array to a string and use [`parse()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/index.html#Base.parse), but that sounds inefficient, and also wouldn't work for bases > 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be written directly within the documentation of `digits`:

```
help?> digits
search: digits digits! ndigits isdigit isxdigit disable_sigint

  digits([T<:Integer], n::Integer; base::T = 10, pad::Integer = 1)

  Return an array with element type T (default Int) of the digits of n in the given base,
  optionally padded with zeros to a specified size. More significant digits are at higher
  indices, such that n == sum([digits[k]*base^(k-1) for k=1:length(digits)]).
```

So for your case this will work:

```
julia> d = digits(36, base = 4);

julia> sum([d[k]*4^(k-1) for k=1:length(d)])
36
```

And the above code can be shortened with the dot operator:

```
julia> sum(d.*4 .^(0:(length(d)-1)))
36
```

Comment: Thanks! Not quite the built-in function I was hoping for, but maybe that's as good as it gets. I'll leave this question open a little bit longer.

Comment: You can even use a dot product to shorten it even further: `d' * base.^(0:length(d)-1)`

Answer (score 7):

The previous answers are correct, but there is also the matter of efficiency:

```
sum([x[k]*base^(k-1) for k=1:length(x)])
```

collects the numbers into an array before summing, which causes unnecessary allocations. Skip the brackets to get better performance:

```
sum(x[k]*base^(k-1) for k in 1:length(x))
```

This also allocates an array before summing: `sum(d.*4 .^(0:(length(d)-1)))`

If you really want good performance, though, write a loop and avoid repeated exponentiation:

```
function undigit(d; base=10)
    s = zero(eltype(d))
    mult = one(eltype(d))
    for val in d
        s += val * mult
        mult *= base
    end
    return s
end
```

This has one extra unnecessary multiplication, you could try to figure out some way of skipping that. But the performance is 10-15x better than the other approaches in my tests, and has zero allocations.

**Edit:** There's actually a slight risk to the type handling above. If the input vector and `base` have different integer types, you can get a type instability. This code should behave better:

```
function undigits(d; base=10)
    (s, b) = promote(zero(eltype(d)), base)
    mult = one(s)
    for val in d
        s += val * mult
        mult *= b
    end
    return s
end
```

Comment: This is the right approach. A slower (still better than direct summation), but I think interesting approach uses Polynomials.jl. Where you can write `polyeval(Poly(d), base)`.

Comment: I agree with @BogumiłKamiński your approach is better, slower but more efficient than mine

Answer (score 2):

Using `foldr` and `muladd` for maximum conciseness and efficiency

```
undigits(d; base = 10) = foldr((a, b) -> muladd(base, b, a), d, init=0)
```